# taking a snapshot of complex mutable structure in concurrent environment

Tags: clojure

**Given:** a complex structure of various nested collections, with refs scattered in different levels.

**Need:** A way to take a snapshot of such a structure, while allowing writes to continue to happen in other threads.

So one the "reader" thread needs to read whole complex state in a single long transaction. The "writer" thread meanwhile makes modifications in multiple short transactions. As far as I understand, in such a case STM engine utilizes the refs history.

Here we have some interesting results. E.g., reader reaches some ref in 10 secs after beginning of transaction. Writer modifies this ref each 1 sec. It results in 10 values of ref's history. If it exceeds the ref's `:max-history` limit, the reader transaction will be run *forever*. If it exceeds `:min-history`, transaction may be rerun several times.

But really the reader needs just a single value of ref (the 1st one) and the writer needs just the recent one. All intermediate values in history list are useless. Is there a way to avoid such history overuse?

Thanks.

Comment: "strange time delays" is not a useful question title. You could edit it to some useful question title.

Comment: @Lion, I'd better rewrite whole question, because some things become clearer now

Comment: I re-wrote part of it, and cleaned up the formatting a bit. Unless I've completely missed what you're asking, I think it's clear enough.

Comment: @normalocity, thanks a lot for your editing. English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

To me it's a bit of a "design smell" to have a large structure with lots of nested refs. You are effectively emulating a mutable object graph, [which is a bad idea if you believe Rich Hickey's take on concurrency](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey).

Some various thoughts to try out:

- The idiomatic way to solve this problem in Clojure would be to put the state in a single top-level ref, with everything inside it being immutable. Then the reader can take a snapshot of the entire concurrent state for free (without even needing a transaction). Might be difficult to refactor to this from where you currently are, but I'd say it is best practice.
- If you only want the reader to get a snaphot of the top level ref, you can just deref it directly outside of a transaction. Just be aware that the refs inside may continue to get mutated, so whether this is useful or not depends on the consistency requirements you have for the reader.
- You can do everything within a (dosync...) transaction as normal for both readers and writer. You may get contention and transaction retries, but it may not be an issue.
- You can create a "snapshot" function that quickly traverses the graph and dereferences all the refs within a transaction, returning the result with the refs stripped out (or replaced by new cloned refs). The reader calls snapshot once, then continues to do the rest of it's work after the snapshot is completed.
- You could take a snapshot immediately each time after the writer finishes, and store it separately in an atom. Readers can use this directly (i.e. only the writer thread accesses the live data graph directly)

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is that you need two things:

1. A flag to indicate that the system is in "snapshot write" mode
2. A queue to hold all transactions that occur while the system is in snapshot mode

As far as what to do if the queue is overflows because the snapshot process isn't fast enough, well, there isn't much you can do about that except either optimize that process, or increase the size of your queue - it's going to be a balance that you'll have to strike depending on the needs of you app. It's a delicate balance, and is going to take some pretty extensive testing, depending on how complex your system is.

But you're on the right track. If you basically put the system in "snapshot write mode", then your reader/writer methods should automatically change where they are reading/writing from, so that the thread that is making changes gets all the "current values" and the thread reading the snapshot state is reading all the "snapshot values". You can split these up into separate methods - the snapshot reader will use the "snapshot value" methods, and all other threads will read the "current value" methods.

When the snapshot reader is done with its work, it needs to clear the snapshot state.

If a thread tries to read the "snapshot values" when no "snapshot state" is currently set, they should simply respond with the "current values" instead. No biggie.

Systems that allow snapshots of file systems to be taken for backup purposes, while not preventing new data from being written, follow a similar scheme.

Finally, unless you need to keep a record of all **changes** to the system (i.e. for an audit trail), then the queue of transactions actually doesn't need to be a queue of changes to be applied - it just needs to store the latest value of whatever thing you're changing in the system. When the "snapshot state" is cleared, you simply write all those non-committed values to the system, and call it done. The thing you might want to consider is making a log of those changes yet to be made, in case you need to recover from a crash, and have those changes still applied. The log file will give you a record of what happened, and can let you do this recovery. That's an oversimplification of the recovery process, but that's not really what your question is about, so I'll stop there.

Comment: your recent paragraph is close enough to what I want. The mentioned structure works as an actor, so the only way to modify it is sending the messages to it, each being processed atomically. Having a recent snapshot and a recorded sequence of messages both saved durably, we always can to crash-recover by replaying message sequence from the recent snapshot (assuming all evaluations are deterministic). Snapshots are taken regulary to keep recovery time admissible. Meanwhile, taking a snapshot shouldn't freeze the actor's activity, that was the underlying reason of the topic question

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the state-of-the-art in high-performance concurrency. You should look at the work of Nathan Bronson, and his lab's collaborations with Aleksandar Prokopec, Phil Bagwell and the Scala team.

Binary Tree: 
http://ppl.stanford.edu/papers/ppopp207-bronson.pdf
https://github.com/nbronson/snaptree/

Tree-of-arrays -based Hash Map
http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~prokopec/ctries-snapshot.pdf

However, a quick look at the implementations above should convince you this is not "roll-your-own" territory. I'd try to adapt an off-the-shelf concurrent data structure to your needs if possible. Everything I've linked to is freely available on the JVM, but its not native Clojure as such.